# When I try to typeset pdflatex I get pdftex error on my output console

Tags: errors

When I typeset my latex file with pdflatex, I get an output console with this error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdftex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode.  restricted \write18 enabled. (./PaperOne-03-16-19.tex
! Undefined control sequence. 
l.6 \documentclass
                  [12pt,leqno]{article}
```

Comment: You need to use the `pdflatex` (which loads the LaTeX format) executable, not `pdftex` (which loads pĺain).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which front-end program -- TeXworks, TeXshop, TeXmaker, TeXstudio, etc -- you employ to edit and typeset your LaTeX documents.

Comment: you give us little in the way of clues looks like your using an old 2015 TeX Live on a file in a subdirectory ? and that file has ? five lines of directives before the class definition ? which is possibly a maths article If your running direct from command line it would help to know if you have a main.tex that's including a number of subfiles and what is FIRST error as shown in main.log plus any FIRST error if there is a /PaperOne….log

Comment: @supa-mega-ducky-momo-da-waffle you should use a code block not a quote for error messages, line endings are vital to understand tex errors.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle. Most sites I use have decided on quote formatting for error messages. But I guess not this one; I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle tex error messages are not understandable if you lose the line breaks, eg the one above it is only by the linebreak after the command that shows which command is undefined., the first line shows the line read so far the linebreak is the point of the error and the indented second line is the rest of the source not yet read. if you show it using the quote format all information is lost.

Comment: Thanks again @DavidCarlisle. I'm really new to TeX and I'm really not familiar with how the error messages work. I'll remember how to format them for future edits.